# Set PrintArea for a separate workbook

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I'm failing to set the print area for an external, temporary, workbook.  I have a main sub which I use to move to the private sub below.  In the main sub, I have defined the `tempWB` properly, however, I can't seem to get it to work in the private sub.  I get this error: [image: this error]

It works if I change the workbook to `ThisWorkbook`, but not for the outside workbook.

```
Private Sub Format(rwCnt As Long, lCol As Long, lColName As String, tempWB As Workbook)

    Dim pArea As Range
    rwCnt = rwCnt + 11

    With tempWB.Worksheets(1)
        Set pArea = .Range("A1:" & lColName & rwCnt)
        With .PageSetup
            .PrintArea = pArea
            .PrintTitleRows = "$2:$2"
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            With ActiveWindow
                If .FreezePanes Then .FreezePanes = False
                .SplitColumn = 0
                .SplitRow = 2
                .FreezePanes = True
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Looks like `.PrintArea` expects a string. Try `pArea.Address`, or just that string: `"A1:" & lColName & rwCnt`.

Comment: @BigBen - That's it! Any reason why it would work for `ThisWorkbook` without a string? Also, please post your answer as an answer so you can receive reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it would work for `ThisWorkbook` as is, but from the [`PrintArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printarea) documentation, note that `PrintArea` expects a `String`.

Either change this to

```
.PrintArea = pArea.Address
```

Or just use the string directly:

```
.PrintArea = "A1:" & lColName & rwCnt
```